# In Visual studio 2022, How To add IConfiguration and add configuration in Program.cs like startup.cs?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

[image]
I need to add a configuration and to customize accordingly.

In previous versions there is a class specifically for configuration in the startup.cs file. I need to know how to add configuration in program.cs.

Comment: Please show code as *text* rather than screenshots.

Comment: When we program, we will encounter many packages that need to be added manually.

VS has a corresponding smart function for this, you only need to use [Alt+Enter or Ctrl+.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KhhmV.png) to [quickly add](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mEA7x.png) the corresponding package.

Answer (score 1):

We can do this:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
//Get the instance of the IConfiguration service
var configuration = builder.Configuration;
//We can configure configuration variables of type IConfiguration and get a value 
var vTestValue = configuration.GetValue<string>("TestValue");
```

Answer (score 0):

`IConfiguration` interface is located in `Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration` namespace. You could install [Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration/) nuget, and get access to IConfiguration interface.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the configuration like so:

`IConfiguration configuration = builder.Configuration;`

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this to simulate Startup.cs and then have IConfiguration. Personally, I find Startup.cs more readable.
In you appsettings:

```
"Employee": {
    "Title": "Mr",
    "Name": "Joe Smith"
 }
```

Corresponding POCO:

```
public class EmployeeOptions
{
    public const string Employee = "Employee";
    public string Title { get; set; } = String.Empty;
    public string Name { get; set; } = String.Empty;
}
```

Now, either you can use IOptions or IOptionsSnapshot in your controller or service, or you can dependency injection like below in Startup.cs.

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
            var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
            var startup = new Startup(builder.Configuration);
            startup.RegisterServices(builder.Services);

            var app = builder.Build();
            startup.SetupMiddlewares(app);

            app.Run();
  } }
```

Then create a file called Startup.cs and inject IConfiguration.

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    public void RegisterServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.Configure<EmployeeOptions>(
        Configuration.GetSection(EmployeeOptions.Employee));
    }

    public void SetupMiddlewares(WebApplication app)
    {
        // Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
            // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseAuthorization();
        
        app.MapControllerRoute(
            name: "default",
            pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
    }
}
```